# How to change the value of BehaviorSubject using map/filter/find/findIndex in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

***TS***

```
  arrData = new BehaviorSubject<any>([]);

  ngOnInit() {
    const dataArr1 = [
      {
        id: '1',
        name: 'Room1',
        spinning: true
      },
      {
        id: '2',
        name: 'Room2',
        spinning: true
      },
      {
        id: '3',
        name: 'Room3',
        spinning: true
      },
      {
        id: '4',
        name: 'Room4',
        spinning: true
      }
    ];

    this.arrData.next(dataArr1);

    const url = { id: '2', name: 'Room2', link: '/api/conditions'}
    const arr = new Array();
    arr.push(url);

    this.arrData.value.map((item: any) => {
      return {
        id: item.id,
        name: item.name,
        spinning: arr.findIndex(e => {
          return e.id === item.id
        }) === -1
      }
    });
    console.log(this.arrData.value);
  }
```

here's the sample output:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-msovvq?file=src/app/app.component.ts

What I'm trying to do here is to change the value of spinning to false.

in the example there's data object `{ id: 2, name: 'Room2' }` then I push it to make it an array.

where I used the findIndex where dataArr1 id === arr id, but the problem here it doesn't change the spinning value to false of dataArr1.

it still the same.

```
[
      {
        id: '1',
        name: 'Room1',
        spinning: true
      },
      {
        id: '2',
        name: 'Room2',
        spinning: true
      },
      {
        id: '3',
        name: 'Room3',
        spinning: true
      },
      {
        id: '4',
        name: 'Room4',
        spinning: true
      }
    ];
```

it should be like this.

```
[
      {
        id: '1',
        name: 'Room1',
        spinning: true
      },
      {
        id: '2',
        name: 'Room2',
        spinning: false
      },
      {
        id: '3',
        name: 'Room3',
        spinning: true
      },
      {
        id: '4',
        name: 'Room4',
        spinning: true
      }
    ];
```

the `Room2` spinning will change to false.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you using map along with filter like this. Map and filter return a new array, not change value itself, so rebind the result to the variable.

```
dataArr1 = dataArr1.map(item => {
  return {
    id: item.id,
    name: item.name,
    spinning: dataArr2.findIndex(e => {
      return e.id === item.id
    }) === -1
  }
})
```

This is the result, is this what you expected?

```
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "Room1",
    "spinning": false
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "Room2",
    "spinning": false
  },
  {
    "id": "3",
    "name": "Room3",
    "spinning": false
  },
  {
    "id": "4",
    "name": "Room4",
    "spinning": true
  }
]
```

Comment: what if the data on dataArr2 is { id: '1', name: 'room1' } ? cause I'm having an error on findIndex

Comment: If it is array, it should be available for `findIndex`, https://developer.mozilla.org/vi/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex

Comment: I updated my code. can you check on it? also I added the link

Comment: ```this.arrData.next(this.arrData.value.map((item: any) => {
      return {
        id: item.id,
        name: item.name,
        spinning: arr.findIndex(e => {
          return e.id === item.id
        }) === -1
      }
    }));
```
you should trigger the subject to change value

Answer (score 1):

Using [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/)

```
let tmp = [
      {
        id: '1',
        name: 'Room1',
        spinning: true
      },
      {
        id: '2',
        name: 'Room2',
        spinning: true
      },
      {
        id: '3',
        name: 'Room3',
        spinning: true
      },
      {
        id: '4',
        name: 'Room4',
        spinning: true
      }
    ];
```

Since we are only using id to find:

```
let url =  { id: '2', name: 'Room2', link: '/api/conditions'}

let _tmp_row= _.find(tmp,{id:url['id']})
_tmp_row.spinning = false
```

Once you find the element as per your pattern you can change the object property as per you like. Since this object is not cloned it will directly update the changes to the main array of objects.

Comment: can you create from the stackblitz? what is the value of x?